# What approach should one take to implement onboading in a web application?

Tags: javascript, user-experience

I want to build onboarding in to my web app. See the attached image for an example. I would like to be more specific, but I am not sure what approach to take.

[image: Marquee onboarding]

If there are resources that you can point me to, it will be great.

Also, how does one ensure that these onboarding steps are only shown once? Do we persist it in database or use any other approach?

Comment: A cross browser solution would probably involve the overlay to have the darkened area with the circle as background. Then you would need to calculate the background position for the given elements. And yes, it would probably be smart to store shown items in a database, people usually don't like getting the same information thrown at them again and again. Just load it into javascript when the page is loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [`chardin.js`](http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/).

As for persistence, I would go for database storing. If you use cookies, localStorage, etc. your users will see instructions if they use another browser or a different computer.

Comment: Chardin looks immensely useful. Thanks. I will try it out and then accept your answer.